# LoL Terrain Question Closure. (Wrong Closing Reason?)

Tags: discussion, closing

So, while revewing I came across a question from '12.

[This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60473/what-skills-spells-gap-closers-or-extenders-can-cross-terrains-such-as-trees-w) was closed for being 'not a real question'.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.

It's really not that difficult, LoL is a game played on a 2D map which is designed to look 3D. Due to that, there is no height parameter, and different mobility abilities (jumps, teleports and dashes) are done visually differently, but in practice they are just a 'faster move' on a 2D axis.
Since different walls have different thicknesses, some abilities can cross some walls but not others. Some dashes can't even cross walls. So, it's not difficult to tell what's being asked.

> This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

It's not ambiguous. It's quite clear actually. It's also not Incomplete, it targets the audience that knows about LoL mechanics and as such the explanation I just gave isn't even necessary if you're able to answer the question (remember .SE is a community for enthusiasts to receive answers from experts).

---

If anything being 'not a question' is the last thing that that question is. If anything the question is Off-Topic due to being a list type answer due to the fact that League has around 140 playable characters, with at least a third of those being able to use an ability that can be in the scope of this question.

---

Even if this is 4 years too late, it's still bulldung. If you don't understand a question, because you don't understand the topic, don't mess with it, because this kind of stuff can fly under the radar for... well, in this case, 4 years.

While that question in particular should be closed, it's closed for the wrong reasons. It's a shame since that gives Arqade a bad image and is in general a lazy thing to do.

In the future, please do try to be more careful with your closures

Comment: Yes, [you should know what you're talking about when closing questions.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11619/people-who-comment-or-action-questions-when-they-dont-play-the-games-themselves/11623#11623) However I simply cannot get worked up by how we might have picked the wrong reason to close one question four years ago, sorry.

Comment: *"If anything the question is Off-Topic due to being a list type answer due to the fact that League has around 140 playable characters, with at least a third of those being able to use an ability that can be in the scope of this question."* Or 'Too Broad', which is also a close reason.

Comment: @Robotnik 131 to be exact iirc.

Answer (score 5):

The mod who closed that question is actually very well-versed in League of Legends. Accusing him of not knowing the topic area is simply incorrect.

Additionally, "not a real question" is no longer even an option for close reasons, probably because it's a confusing concept for people who come across SE sites for the first time. They changed to a new set of close reasons that are hopefully more obvious in their use on the first pass. That was, however, a valid close at the time, under the **overly broad** wording you yourself quoted. As the relevant comment from the question says:

> You're asking for a list, not the answer to a question. If are interested in knowing about whether a specific skill can cross a certain point of terrain, that would be more acceptable.

In this case, "too broad", one of our current close reasons, still fits this question really well, so there's no reason to re-open it. We don't have a police force going around looking at 4-year-old questions closed for old reasons and updating the reasons, because that's a waste of time.

The real question here is why this question hasn't been automatically deleted, since that's what should happen to closed questions that aren't duplicates. I've gone ahead and corrected that issue.

Comment: Except the question could very well be edited into being on-topic and too broad.

Comment: @Oak If the question can be edited to a state where it's still close-worthy, what are you trying to save?

Comment: For one it's deleted now. And secondly, my issue isn't with the question being closed. It's just that it's not the first question that I see being closed for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Oak It *wasn't* closed for the wrong reason. In 2012, "not a real question" was the close reason used for questions, like this one, that were too broad.

Comment: @Oak If this is a widespread problem then you should provide several recent examples (none older than a year), instead of just one example from four years ago (which wasn't even closed incorrectly).